# java global varibales can not be changed android studio

Tags: java, android, boolean

I don't know if I'm doing this correctly, I made a java file var.java

```
public class var {
   public  static  boolean u = true ;
}
```

in the main activity I have

```
buUn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //var.u = !var.u ;
        if (var.u = true) {
            var.u = false;
        } else {
            var.u = true  ;
        }

        if (var.u = false){
            txtx.setText("1");
        } else {
            txtx.setText("2");
        }
    }
});
```

u is always `true` no matter what, `txtx` text is `2`, even if `i` change it value in the `var.java` to `false` **i** keep getting `2`.

Comment: You're incorrectly using `=` for comparison instead of `==`. Fix your typos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have wrong checking your conditions. Booleans are compared with `==` operator. Not with a single `=` that is used for declaring a value. So please remember:

- `=` is an **assignment**
- `==` is a **comparision**

This is the correct code:

```
if (var.u == true) {
   var.u = false;
} else {
   var.u = true;
}

if (var.u == false) {
   txtx.setText("1");
} else {
   txtx.setText("2");
}
```

To make it shorter, you can use `!` as the negation operator meaning **not**.

```
if (var.u) {
   var.u = false;
} else {
   var.u = true;
}

if (!var.u) {
   txtx.setText("1");
} else {
   txtx.setText("2");
}
```

---

Finally to make it the as shortest as possible, try this out:

```
var.u = !var.u;
var.u ? txtx.setText("2") : txtx.setText("1");
```

Answer (score 0):

comparators in Java uses `==`

like that:

```
     //  var.u = !var.u ;
        if (var.u == true){
            var.u = false ;
        }else {
            var.u = true  ;
        }


        if (var.u == false){
            txtx.setText("1");

        } else {
            txtx.setText("2");
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

TRY THIS OUT >>

> Problem with `if (var.u = true)` this line actually. You are not using Relation (==) Operator. Instead of this what you are doing is Using **Assignment** (`=`) at each time this line is getting executed `true` is assigned to the Variable `var.u`.

Solution :>

```
             if (var.u) //its a boolean so no need to use Relational Operatior
                var.u = false ;
             else
                var.u = true  ;
             if (!var.u)   // !(not) Operator will check if it is false.
                txtx.setText("1");
             else 
                txtx.setText("2");
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the public static variable in the var class you can make int private and non static and add getters and setters, and in the constructor of the var class you can initialize that variable to true, so that when you create the instance of var you will have the value of u to true.

In your case the problem is in the comparision, you don't ask if the value is true, but you tell that the value is trure:

if (var.u = true){
is needed:
if (var.u == true){